# What's the best tool for monitoring individual hard drive activity?

Tags: hard-drive

I have 2 drives in my system. One for the OS, and one for backups. I was wondering if there is a tool that can monitor the read/write activity of each individual drive as opposed to what indicator-multiload does which shows activity of both drives.

Comment: Monitor for what? Health? General activity? Temperature?

Comment: Does this resource give any pointers? https://www.opsdash.com/blog/disk-monitoring-linux.html Opinion based questions are off topic here.